# How to use casperjs arvgs to evaluate?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, exec, casperjs, argv

I wanna know how to solve this problem...

do you know casperjs.cli?
I command in cmd 'casperjs casperjs/test.js argv'

```
casper.start('https://map.naver.com/');
casper.then(function() {
    console.log(casper.cli.has(0));
    console.log(casper.cli.get(0));
    const input = casper.cli.get(0);
    console.log(input);
    var value = this.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("search-input").value = input;
        var value = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
        document.getElementsByClassName("nclicks(STA.go)")[0].click();
        return value;
    });
})
casper.then(function(){
    var result = this.evaluate(function(){
        var value = $('.srt_tit').text();
        return value
    })
    console.log(result);
});
casper.run();
```

If I use not argv and real type, the result is good.
but if I use caspercli, there is no result...
How to use argv in casperjs??? I want to use this casper module on my nodejs server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I call your code with

`casperjs test.js "cafe"`

it normally prints out this value in the following lines

```
console.log(casper.cli.has(0));
console.log(casper.cli.get(0));
const input = casper.cli.get(0);
console.log(input);
```

as

```
true
cafe
cafe
```

So that part should work...